# Getting Started w/ SurveyMonkey API v3

Tags: python, surveymonkey

I'm brand new to working with the SurveyMonkey API, and relatively new to Python/API work in general. I'm trying to build a very simple program that will, for starters, pull the list of surveys on my SurveyMonkey account.

Here's what I'm starting with:

```
import requests
import json

client = requests.session()
client.headers = {
    "Authorization": "bearer %s" % "<MY_ACCESS_TOKEN>",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}
client.params = {
    "api_key" : "<MY_API_KEY>"
}

HOST = "https://api.surveymonkey.net"
SURVEY_LIST_ENDPOINT = "/v3/surveys/get_survey_list"

uri = "%s%s" % (HOST, SURVEY_LIST_ENDPOINT)

data = {}
response = client.get(uri, data=json.dumps(data))
response_json = response.json()
survey_list = response_json["data"]["surveys"]
```

When run, this code results in the following error:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed
```

Any ideas on where I'm going wrong? Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The endpoint you were using`/v3/surveys/get_survey_list` does not exist in V3, it does exist in V2 (`/v2/surveys/get_survey_list`).

See [here](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#surveys) for get survey list in v3. Try something like:

```
import requests

client = requests.session()

headers = {
    "Authorization": "bearer %s" % "<MY_ACCESS_TOKEN>",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}
params = {
    "api_key" : "<MY_API_KEY>"
}

HOST = "https://api.surveymonkey.net"
SURVEY_LIST_ENDPOINT = "/v3/surveys"

uri = "%s%s" % (HOST, SURVEY_LIST_ENDPOINT)

response = client.get(uri, params=params, headers=headers)
response_json = response.json()
survey_list = response_json["data"]["surveys"]
```

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for the prompt reply!

I tried using your exact code and am still receiving the CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED error. I'm using Python 2.7. It would appear as if the issue has something to do with the certificate being used...I really have no idea :(

Comment: Hmm that seems weird, if you add `verify=False` in the client.get() request then it'll stop checking that (not recommended for production use) but you shouldn't need to. I just did it and I didn't get that issue.

Comment: Using verify=False resolved my issue. Thank you again for the help!

Comment: Not sure but I think the host changed to https://api.surveymonkey.com, doesn't it?